# React useReducer not showing value from array.reduce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useReducer to hold some state as seen in the code below but it is not returning the value from the array reducer function.

```js
  let [entriesByEmployer, dispatchEntriesByEmployer] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => {
      const reducer = (employerEntries, entry) => {
        console.log("adding to employerEntries");
        employerEntries[entry.employerId] = employerEntries[entry.employerId] || [];
        employerEntries[entry.employerId].push(entry);
        console.log(employerEntries);
        return employerEntries;
      };
      return batchEntries.reduce(reducer, []);
    },
    []
  );
```

The Process:

- When I click a button on the screen it gets info from the DB
- that info is stored in the batchEntries variable.
- I use useEffect to fire the dispatchEntriesByEmployer when batchEntries is changed
- which causes the reducer to run.

I know that the internal reduce function runs because if I wrap it in a console log it outputs the data I expect to the console.

```js
console.log(batchEntries.reduce(reducer, []));
```

However when I return the result of the reduce function, the React DevTools shows "Reducer: Array (empty)" when I inspect the component

Comment: Why are you using useReducer, it does not seem like you need an actual reducer as your function is ignoring both state and action argument. Should you be using useState instead? It's not because you're using array.reduce that you should be using useReducer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the reducer itself. Because I was assigning array keys it was not showing the array. Instead I changed it into an object

```js
 let [entriesByEmployer, dispatchEntriesByEmployer] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => {
      const reducer = (employerEntries, entry) => {
        console.log("adding to employerEntries");
        employerEntries[entry.employerId] = employerEntries[entry.employerId] || [];
        employerEntries[entry.employerId].push(entry);
        console.log(employerEntries);
        return employerEntries;
      };
      return batchEntries.reduce(reducer, {});
    },
    {}
  );
```